# Правильно реализовать создание и подключение плагинов в коде CMS

Tags: php, база-данных, mvc, cms

CMS имеет стандартную структуру: сайт и админку. В админке с использованием TinyMCE-редактора пользователь (контент-менеджер) создает страницы. Некоторые страницы при этом должны иметь различные html-объекты: (формы заказа и отправки отзывов, фото-галерея и другие). Естественно, такие объекты (плагины) должны создаваться отдельно от редактора и затем интегрироваться в страницу.

На текущий момент у меня такая реализация работы плагина:

При создании, например, **страницы заказа услуги**, пользователь прописывает в редакторе:

```
Дорогой вы наш пользователь! На этой странице вы можете сделать заказ услуги.
{{order_service}}
```

Данный текст сохраняется в БД. При обращении к странице, Модель, отвечающая за вывод страниц сайта, парсит регуляркой полученные данные из БД и при наличии одноименного файла order_service.php подключает его (require "order_service.php"). Код данного файла генерирует html-форму заказа услуги и вставляет ее вместо {{order_service}}. Полученная html-страница с формой выводится в браузер.

Файл order_service.php также содержит код обработки поступивших пост-данных, делает запросы к БД (класс-синглтон), осуществляет проверку данных и размещает их в БД.

Вопрос, собственно в том, правильно ли реализована такая технология с точки зрения MVC? Ведь обработка формы и доступ к БД производится не с помощью методов соответствующей модели, а непосредственно в коде самого плагина. Существуют ли более гибкие варианты реализации такого рода плагинов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Сначала коротко и по делу***

Модель делегирует часть обработки плагину, вроде ничего криминального. Всё как надо, если и сам плагин также реализован через MVC.

***Теперь пространный комментарий***

Любые удачные программы, как правило, изменяются. Не всегда возможно предвидеть, *какие* это будут изменения, но можно к ним подготовиться. Если поддерживать хорошую модульность, то будущие изменения будут стоить меньших усилий. Смысл толкового проектирования (применения MVC, да и любых других паттернов) в том, чтобы разделить на модули код, отвечающий за разные задачи, с целью облегчить разработку и сопровождение.

Каждый класс (или исходный файл) должен иметь только одну причину для его изменения: изменилась цветовая гамма сайта — правим вид, обновилась структура таблиц в БД — правим модель... В противном случае для замены одного плагина другим пришлось бы перелопатить половину исходников. А это бы значило, что с системой что-то не так. Если каждый файл исходников у Вас решает какую-то свою задачу, не влезая в чужие, то можно сказать, что модульность системы хорошая или по меньшей мере удовлетворительная.

**P.S.** Вообще, по-моему, нет верных и неверных решений — есть решения, которые в конкретной задаче дадут определённый результат. И если в Вашем проекте описываемое решение позволило добиться *достаточной* гибкости (и не вызовет головной боли в будущем), его можно назвать удачным.

Comment: Тогда вопрос решен! Ведь каждый из плагинов включает в себя  собственные файлы вида и модели, а также отдельный css-файл.